# Drf union serializers for swagger auto schema

Tags: django-rest-framework, swagger, django-serializer, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I've got the otp confirm functionality, and then I need to get response like this:

```
    {
    "token": {
        "refresh": string_refresh_token,
        "access": string_access_token
    },
    "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "email": "test@test.com",
        "phone_number": "+9998889987",
        "first_name": "First Name",
        "last_name": "Last Name",
        "role": id_role_from_profile
    }
}
```

models.py:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    # standard User fields here
    ...

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=ProfileRoles.CHOICES)
```

views.py:

```
class ConfirmOtpView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny, )

    @swagger_auto_schema(request_body=ConfirmOtpSerializer())
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = ConfirmOtpSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        user = serializer.get_update_user()
        profile = user.get_last_profile()
        refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
        refresh['role'] = profile.role
        user_data = UserDetailsTokenSerializer(user, context={'role': profile.role}).data
        token_data = user.get_token(refresh)
        result_data = {
            'token': token_data,
            'user': user_data
        }

        return Response(data=result_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

First problem - response in my swagger is empty. Second problem: I want create serializer for moving result data logic from view to new UserTokenSerializer like this:

```
class UserDetailsTokenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    role = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'phone_number', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'role')

    def get_role(self, obj):
        profile = obj.get_last_profile()
        role = profile.role
        return role


class UserTokenSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    user = UserDetailsTokenSerializer()
    token = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        fields = ('user', 'token')

    def get_token(self, obj):
        refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(obj)
        refresh['role'] = self.context.get('role')
        data = {
            "refresh": str(refresh),
            "access": str(refresh.access_token)
        }
        return data
```

But when I've tried UserTokenSerializer(context={'user': user}).data its give me empty data. And how can I call role from UserDetailsTokenSerializer in get_token method?
Finally I need swagger decorator like this:

```
@swagger_auto_schema(request_body=ConfirmOtpSerializer(), responses={200: UserTokenSerializer()})
```